# AWS: Restarting SVN server after reboot - currently "unable to connect to a repository at URL" and "no repository found"

Tags: amazon-web-services, svn

My AWS server was recently rebooted, and on it I had my SVN repository hosted.  The SVN path was like so:

```
svn://ec2-54-xxx-xx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/myproject
```

Now when I try to visit it with TortiseSVN I get:

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL
'svn://ec2-54-xxx-xx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/myproject'
No repository found in
'svn://ec2-54-xxx-xx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/myproject'
```

When I get into my server I run the following

```
cd /home/svn/myproject
sudo /usr/bin/svnserve -d
```

Sure enough I see it running:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-xxx-xx-xxx svn]$ ps -ef | grep svn
root     29145     1  0 21:02 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/svnserve -d
ec2-user 29157 29108  0 21:02 pts/4    00:00:00 grep svn
```

But my attempts to hit it fail, regardless.  I have been using the `svn://` before, but when I tried `https://` it gave me `Error running context: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it` and `http://` resulted in `Redirect cycle detected for URL`

Any suggestions on what I'm missing?  I'm almost certain it's something simple and dumb, but I've been working it for over 60 minutes now.

Comment: Is the IP address of the server the same or did it change?

Comment: It appears to be unchanged.  The domain resolves as it did before.  That is, a file which was located at `http://ec2-54-xxx-xx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/log/test.txt` was not reachable when the server was shut down, but as soon as I restarted `httpd` it was back up.  (I only give that specific example because it's how I noticed the server was down in the first place.)